Pivoting datasets with SQL
Thank you all in advance. I've never done pivoting with SQL and after quite a while trying to figure it out, I haven't been successful.
Below is a small sample of my data set and I'm hoping to pivot the data by month and have separate rows for each year.
The below comes from:
SELECT source,
region,
period,
revenue,
tax_rate,
users
FROM source_data


Ideally, the desired output would look something similar to the below but I'm just not sure how to get to this point using SQL:


Have you checked the official BigQuery documentation that contains a good example on how to use the PIVOT operator?
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator

I used three pivots on BigQuery to achieve something similar to the image you have above. Query below.
WITH
  table_a AS (
  SELECT
    *EXCEPT(period),
    SPLIT(period,"-")[
  OFFSET
    (0)] AS period,
    FORMAT_DATE('%B', CAST(CONCAT(period,"-01") AS date)) AS month,
    FORMAT_DATE('%B', CAST(CONCAT(period,"-01") AS date)) AS month2,
    FORMAT_DATE('%B', CAST(CONCAT(period,"-01") AS date)) AS month3
  FROM
    `optimal-weft-418017.78268160.78268160_01` ),
  table_b AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    table_a PIVOT ( MIN(revenue) AS revenue FOR month IN ('January') )),
  table_c AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    table_b PIVOT ( MIN(tax_rate) AS tax_rate FOR month2 IN ('January') ) ),
  table_d AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    table_c PIVOT ( MIN(Users) AS Users FOR month3 IN ('January') ) )
SELECT
  SOURCE,
  region,
  period,
  CONCAT("Revenue: ",revenue_january,"\nTax Rate: ",tax_rate_January,"\n Users: ",users_january) as info
FROM
  table_d

Sample input table:



Source
Region
Period
Revenue
Tax Rate
Users




Source A
Region I
2021-01
18440150.48
0.14
0


Source B
Region VII
2021-01
272382497.2
0.14
30575905


Source C
Region VI
2021-01
23244127.87
0.14
2514972



Sample output table:



source
region
period
Jan_info




Source A
Region I
2021
Revenue: 18440150.48, Tax Rate: 0.14,  Users: 0


Source B
Region VII
2021
Revenue: 272382497.2, Tax Rate: 0.14,  Users: 30575905


Source C
Region VI
2021
Revenue: 23244127.87, Tax Rate: 0.14,  Users: 2514972



Some things to note:  You'll have to add the remaining months in the three pivots as 'February','March', etc. to have every month's aggregated data as per your image above.
